# Thread reliability: log file shows function that I call a lot did not reach return statement randomly

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

edit: I found the cause, because the function statements are wrapped inside a try/catch clause,  the function could not reach  couldnt reach the statetement where the exit code would`ve been logged.

I am now also logging inside the catch clause.

If I find something new I'll let you know.

I'm making an UI application in VB.NET that creates Processes to run some command line applications and get the strings they return.

All this calls are made in a BackgroundWorker thread.

The problem is my application is not reliable.

Sometimes it works fine,sometimes the function does not reach the return statement.

I see this because I log information in a text file before the function returns.

Is there something I am not doing? This is the first time I use backgroundworker.

If you need more information I will gladly give you.

edit: the information returned by the ExecuteCommand function I dont use in the UI, I create an Excel file with it.
edit: the function I call

```
Public Function ExecuteCommand(ByVal Command As String) As String
    Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = MainForm.BackgroundWorker1
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions()
    Try
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim startTime As Date
        Dim endTime As Date
        Dim procStartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " & Command)


        objLog.LogAction("[" & Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss") & "]" & " " & Command.ToString)
        startTime = Now
        ' The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        ' This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        ' Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        ' Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()

        AddHandler proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf StdOutputDataHandler
        sStdOutput = New StringBuilder()

        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo
        proc.Start()

        proc.BeginOutputReadLine()





        Dim exitCode As Integer
        proc.WaitForExit()
        exitCode = proc.ExitCode




        Dim rsStdOut As String = String.Empty
        If sStdOutput.Length > 0 Then
            rsStdOut = sStdOutput.ToString
        End If


        proc.Close()
        proc = Nothing
        endTime = Now
        Dim elapsed As String
        elapsed = (endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString
        elapsed = elapsed.Substring(0, elapsed.IndexOf(".") + 4)
        objLog.LogAction("[" & Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss") & "]" & " exit code: " & exitCode.ToString() + vbCrLf + vbTab + "Command execution took " + elapsed + " seconds" + vbCrLf)


        If exitCode <> 0 Then
            result = ERROR_MESSAGE
        Else
            result = rsStdOut
        End If


        result = result.Trim()
        If result.Length > 1 Then
            'result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1)
        End If

        'result = Regex.Replace(result, "\n", RESULT_SPLITER)

        Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ERROR_MESSAGE
    End Try


End Function
```

and the log file excerpt:

```
[13:44:05] si viewproject -P project -Y --projectRevision 1.4
[13:44:05] si viewproject -P project -Y --projectRevision 1.5
[13:44:05] si viewproject -P project -Y --projectRevision 1.6
[13:44:06] exit code: 0
Command execution took 0.079 seconds

[13:44:06] si viewproject -P project -Y --projectRevision 1.7
[13:44:06] exit code: 0
Command execution took 0.082 seconds
```

after each line that represents a command there should be an exit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug in my code. The line:

```
elapsed = elapsed.Substring(0, elapsed.IndexOf(".") + 4)
```

threw the exception

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
```

because the running time of a command varied and sometime there were not 4 digits after the "."

My problem had nothing to do with BackgroundWorker.